# Не могу сделать чтобы бордеры образовали одну сплошную линию

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-events

Есть пример как это должно выглядеть, но я не могу сделать так, чтобы был один бордер серый внизу, при клике на текст, на то же место но под текстом добавлялся новый бордер с другим текстом (как на скриншоте)
UPD: виглядает сейчас это так: https://jsfiddle.net/p1e0/ro7m5j83/2/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
}

.p1 {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.active {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

.inactive-color {
  color: rgb(157, 164, 174);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="p1 active">Published</span>
  <span class="p2 inactive-color">Received</span>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код, где вы это пытаетесь сделать. И html и css

Comment: Обновил пост @newman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}

span {
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: #999;
  padding: 5px;
}

.active {
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Published</span>
  <span class="active">Received</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо это то что мне было нужно, совсем забыл про тени= )

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете сделать бордер всему меню снизу. Будет одна сплошная линия для всех кнопок. А отдельно под каждую кнопку завести псевдокласс `:hover` который будет срабатывать при наведении.

```
.class:hover{
   border-bottom: 2px solid #82b6fd;
}
```

К сожалению Вы не предоставили код самого меню, сложно сказать что именно Вам подойдёт лучше.

Как вариант сделать `border-bottom: 2px solid #e7e7e7;` всем кнопкам, а с помощью псевдокласса `:hover` будет перекрываться первый стиль.

Comment: Да такой вариант подойдет, но получаю бордер на 1 пиксель выше

Comment: Значит вам просто нужно убрать этот 1 пиксель.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container">
   <span class="p1">Published</span>
   <span class="p2">Received</span>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px gray solid;  
}

.p1 {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.active {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;  
}

const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.container span');
navItems.forEach(navItem => {
    navItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        navItems.forEach(navItem => {
            navItem.classList.remove('active');
        });
        navItem.classList.add('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, хорошый способ сделать при наведени, а если хотим сделать событие например при клике, додавался даный клас?

Comment: Поправил свой ответ.